# Regex not accepting single character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using following regex to have validation like

- String should not start with space
- String should be alpha numeric with space, hyphen and underscore in them

  `[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1nC7cu4tsGR5qiFP)

But this is NOT accepting single character input. Can anyone please help me to achieve the same validation and also accept a single character alpha numeric?

Comment: Would `a----------------b` be valid?

Comment: For clarity (there are already a few *extremely* similar correct answers): yours did not accept a single character because it specifies at least *two*: the first inside the first set of `[..]` (and which accepts *anything* except those, even `$` or `<`), then another set which accepts *one or more* of the specified set.

Comment: @thg435 yes its valid

Comment: @Jongware you are right, I failed to understand that. Regex freaks me out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^[\w-][\w\s-]*$
```

This will let first character be hyphen OR a alpha-num but rest 0 OR more characters be any combination of alpha-num OR space OR hyphen

Please note `\w` represents `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

**If you only want first character to be alpha-num then use:**

```
^\w[\w\s-]*$
```

Comment: @OGHaza: It should have been single escaping, but OP had double escaping originally and I copied over. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$` is looking for:

- One character that is not a hyphen or space; then
- One more more alpha-numberic, underscore, space or hyphen characters.

So it requires at least two characters to find a match.

If you take the second character set `[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]` and exclude space and hyphen from it (as you require at the beginning of the string) then you get `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

So, you want to match on:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]*$
```

- One character that can be alpha-numeric or an underscore (at the start of the string); then
- Zero or more subsequent alpha-numberic, underscore, space or hyphen characters.

Since `\w` is an equivalent regular expression character class to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` then this can be simplified to:

```
^\w[\w\s-]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

So your string should not *not* start with "not space or hyphen" but rather the inverse: with 'a-z, 0-9, _'.

Try this instead:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]*$
```

One character in the first character class is required, and does not contain the space or hyphen. After that, anything goes -- *zero* or more times.